# UNION SQL Statement in VBScript

Tags: sql, vbscript

I wrote a little script to get info out if MSI files. It works fine for simple SELECT statements. However when I use the following one it doesn't

```
SELECT Dialog_, Control, Text FROM Control 
UNION SELECT 'UIText',Key,Text from UIText
```

I get the error msg

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error 1A8: Object required
```

I open the Database like this

```
Wscript.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
```

Is the UNION statement not supported?

Comment: What code do you actually use to run the query?

Comment: I use   Set view = database.OpenView("SELECT Dialog_, Control, Text FROM Control UNION SELECT 'UIText',Key,Text from UIText")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNION isn't mentioned in the [SQL Syntax supported by the Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372021.aspx), so it's probably not supported.